# pread not returning the expected data

Tags: c

I'm trying to read the data from the following file into segments using pread.

[image]

The first part of the data is 128 bytes and is a char array.  The next 2 values are int.  The final value is a (void *) which was a char[100].

I've been able to read all but the last value with the following code, but I cannot get "hello, world" to print out.

```
    int start = 0;
    char segment_name[128];
    ssize_t result = pread(fd, segment_name, 128, start);
    start += result;
    printf("segment name: %s\n", segment_name);

    int seg_size = 0;
    result = pread(fd, &seg_size, sizeof(int), start);
    start += result;
    printf("segment size: %i\n", seg_size);

    int update_size  = 0;
    result = pread(fd, &update_size , sizeof(int), start);
    start += result;
    printf("update_size: %i\n", update_size );

    void *segment_data = malloc(update_size);
    result = pread(fd, segment_data, update_size, start);
    printf("segment data: %s\n", (char *)segment_data);
```

Comment: there are 3 ints before "hello, world" (assuming 32-bit int)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I've been beating my head against this for over an hour!